# tikz error:Missing number, treated as zero. \end{frame}

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

It is written in documentclass beamer. Additionally, the code \captionof{}{} doesn't work either.

```
    \begin{frame}{Motivation}
    \begin{center}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=4.521in,
    height=3.566in,
    at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=10,
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    legend style={at={(0.658,0.788)},anchor=south west,legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black}
    ]
    \draw[color=red]    plot (\x,{-ln(\x)})             node[right] {$f(x) =ln(x)$};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}


    Caption
        \end{center}
   \end{frame}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, MarcoG beat me for few minutes ... but in my suggestion I omit all surplus parts of code and use `figure` environment with caption. Also I use usual pgfplots yntax for such diagrams:

**Edit:**
In your MWE the domain of function is not defined, so pgfplots consider default domain. Consequently, the function was draw only on this domain regardles that `xmax` is bigger)  In the first version of answer, I follow your code (to much), now I add domain `domain=0:8` (8 I select that the label of function is still inside of graph) and obtain the result below:

```
documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Motivation}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.521in,
height=3.566in,
scale only axis,
xmin=-0,
xmax=10,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.658,0.788)},anchor=south west,
              legend cell align=left, align=left, 
              draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot+[domain=0:8] {-ln(\x)}  node[right] {$f(x)=ln(x)$};
\legend{f(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

In case that you like to present more function on graph, just add `addplot[...] { ...}` into code. For example as you ask in comment:

```
 \addplot+[domain=0.1:8] {1/(4*\x)} node[right] {$y(x)=1/(4x)$};
```

and also add this function into `legend`:

```
 \legend{f(x),y(x)};
```

In this case the graph is:

[image]

**Addendum:**
in comments are may subquestions. I try to add answers in comment too, but for completnes let mi sumirised it in MWE and picrure with graph (with this would be easy check, if I correctly undersatand them :-)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Motivation}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.521in,
height=3.566in,
scale only axis,
xmin= 0, xmax=10,
ymin=-2.5, ymax=2.5,
ticks=none,% no numbers
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.658,0.788)},anchor=south west,
              legend cell align=left, align=left, 
              draw=white!15!black},
]
\addplot+[domain=0.0:10] {-ln(\x)}  node[right] {$f(x)=ln(x)$};
\addplot+[domain=0.1:10] {1/(4*\x)} node[right] {$y(x)=\frac{1}{4x}$};
\legend{f(x),y(x)};
\draw[dashed] (2,-2.5) -- (2,3);% regions x<=2
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (10,0);  % region y<=0
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I change this the function to y=1/4x? And why does the function always end at x=5?

Comment: Because in your (and also mine) MWE is not determined domain of function. So it is used default value, which seems to be 5. See edit of my answer.

Comment: And further:  how can I remove the numbers on axes and the points (rectangle) on function curves?

Comment: How to indicate a region, for example, x\geq2 &&y\geq0?

Comment: Huh, to many sub-questions for an answer. The best advise is: start to read `pgplots` manual :-).  (i): `ticks=none,` (ii) this question is not clear, maybe `\draw[dashed] (2,-2.5) -- (2,3)  (0,0) -- (10,0);` would give what you after. However, for this lines you need add to preamble `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}`

Comment: I know it's too much for a question. Thank you for your patience and detailed answer

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following code. I changed the domain  (commented the `ymin` and `ymax` entries) since the function is mainly negative. Moreover, with `pgfplots` you should use the `\addplot` command instead of `\draw`. See if the following is what you where looking for.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=4.521in,
    height=3.566in,
    at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    %ymin=0,
    %ymax=10,
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    legend style={at={(0.658,0.788)},anchor=south west,legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black}
    ]
    \addplot[color=red] (\x,{-ln(\x)}) node[right] {$f(x) =-ln(x)$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    Caption
   \end{center}
   \end{frame}

\end{document}
```